# Remove last lines in csv file with "Totals" info

Tags: csv, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a large csv file that I'm saving to Google Cloud Storage with the following sample format:

```
id,revenue
1,100
2,100
...
Totals
All,12000
```

Or:

```
title,profit
titanic,200
avatar,400
fox total,600
paramount total,400
grand total,1000
```

I want to be able to remove all lines after and including the Totals, because that isn't really valid information within the csv file (it's more summation information of the csv below the data).

Is there a way to delete this? Currently, we're saving the csv file to Google Cloud Storage and then importing it directly via csv-import in Big Query. Perhaps, there's a way to append row-number to a csv file when importing csv via BigQuery or something similar, so we could do a delete statement at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you delete the MAX() row after importing?

```
#standardSQL
DELETE
FROM `project.dataset.table` 
WHERE revenue = (
  SELECT revenue
  FROM `project.dataset.table` 
  ORDER BY taxi_trips DESC
  LIMIT 1
)
```

Or go for the id "All":

```
#standardSQL
DELETE
FROM `project.dataset.table` 
WHERE id = "All"
```

Comment: how do we know the `max_row`? What if there's not an auto-incrementing ID (modified question above). Also, the id is usually not "All", this is just an example.

Comment: If it's a total that adds all positive numbers, then it has to be the biggest number - or not?

Comment: No, not subtotals or record counts. Maybe a more direct question is: is there a way to add in the row-number to a csv import with BigQuery? Also, isn't this a common case (I see about 1/3 of all csv/excel files I have show totals info at the bottom, and almost always for any financial info.)

Comment: There is no way to do this, but you could [file a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0).

Comment: @ElliottBrossard thanks Elliott, I'll add in a ticket.